# If a sequence is not bounded, does it mean it's divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a sequence is not bounded, does it mean it's divergent?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What exactly did you try? Please [edit] your question to include the details.

Comment: How about $a_n = \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: "Personally I think it's true" $\leadsto$ why do you think it's true? Gut feeling, some evidence, random guess?

Comment: You've edited the question to such an extent that the only existing answer is completely out of context.

Answer (score 3):

You can't prove it because it's not true.  Think about how $n$ is going to infinity.  Is it possible for $a_n$ to go to infinity too, just much more slowly than $n$ does?  That may allow the quotient $\frac{a_n}{n}$ to tend to $0$ even though both numerator and denominator are going to infinity.